# Standard ML : Searching a list of tuples

Tags: list, functional-programming, sml, smlnj

I'm trying to write a function in SML that searches a list of tuples for a string and if it finds the string in the first element of the tuple, it returns the second.

```
fun getFromBlist (name : command, (x,y)::tail : (command*command) list) = 
    if x = name then y else getFromBlist(name, tail)
    | getFromBlist(name, []) = ***** WHAT GOES HERE?!? *****
```

Is there anything that I can use for the base case that will just return nothing? Everything I try, I get an error. I'm open to other suggestions here as well, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [Option](http://sml-family.org/Basis/option.html) structure to return NONE for the base case,
I've slightly reformatted the code, putting the base case first,

As well as returning SOME y for a match, and NONE for the base case.
From there you can use a case statement, or pattern matching to retrieve the result.

```
type command = string;

fun getFromBlist(name, []) = NONE
  | getFromBlist (name : command, (x,y)::tail : (command*command) list) =
    if x = name
      then SOME y
      else getFromBlist(name, tail);
```

Alternatively, depending on what you want, for the base case you could return the empty string "", and return y as you did originally.  It kind of depends on if the empty string is a valid command, and you want to differentiate between that and the base case.

But to summarize the base case, and the result of **then**
must return the same type, be it **string**, or **option**